# H2 data base storage Capacity

Tags: java, h2

I have a small question about storing data on a h2data database. How many records in an h2data database can we maximally store? Is there any limitation? If the data goes beyond this limitation what type of error does it give? Will the whole the system fail, or what else happens?

thank u

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#size_limit

Comment: A default max size of table is 2^64.how to increase the maximum number of table records?

Comment: @Bass I don't think you are aware how large 2^64 is. It is larger than 9'000'000'000'000'000'000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H2 is a *lightweight* database. As so it does have limitations. According to the page cited by  Karthikeyan, the limit of 2^64 rows per table is a hard limit. If you try to write more, the insert will fail.

If you need more powerful databases, you could try the excellent PostgreSQL or MySql or MariaDB which will have less limitations.

Comment: Yes, H2 is a lightweight database... However, I don't think you will ever have even close to 2^64 row per table (with any database), because 2^64 is really large number.

Comment: yes, 2^64 = 18446744073709551616.. thanks @thomas,@serge